# ASP.NET MVC c# published site on GoDaddy, session times out too soon

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I have a ASP.NET MVC c# which I've published on a domain hosted by GoDaddy. However I have an issue regarding session expiration.

In the web.config, I've written:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" 
       defaultUrl="~/Items/Index" 
       timeout="432000" />
```

and

```
<sessionState timeout="6000" />
```

This works fine when running it localhost, however when publishing the site to my domain and logging in, it will usually timeout after only about 10-15 minutes of inactivity.

I've also checked the GoDaddy settings and could only find this, which still seems to be right:

[GoDaddy session settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMpRd.png)

Have I missed something, is there something else that determines session timeout on a server?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sessionstate and forms authentication won't have anything to do with eachother. It could be that the application pool itself is being recycled, or that the application is being torn down due to non-use that is causing the session to expire. If the app pool recycles, unless you are using a state management server or other persistent session storage, session will be reset.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to prevent the application pool from being recycled?

Comment: Recycling the application pool can be critical to the health of an application. You also most likely don't have control over it through GoDaddy unless you have your own dedicated box. Recycling the application pool can be necessary for proper garbage collection of memory as well as ensuring that the database connection pool is healthy.

Comment: Surely it has the smarts to decide that there is sufficient length of inactivity on the site that a recycle won't disrupt general use of the site.  It seems rather pointless if I can't use a site without logging in every few page refreshes..

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your web.config file like below

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1440"/>
```

And also generate a machine key for your application and add it to web.config file as well as

```
<machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="[put decryptionKey here ]" validationKey="[put validationKey here ]"/>
```

Note:The all the above code goes with in the

```
<system.web>...</system.web>
```

Comment: I can confirm this solution still works in 2023. Thank you